# git push to https repository from Intranet application with kerberos authentication

Tags: git, authentication, passwords, kerberos

First of all, I'm fairly new to https, ssl and authentication in general.

I develop an Intranet application which should realize some "push" from a local git repository (hosted on a web server) and a remote repository (hosted on an Unix server).

The web Server is a Windows 2003 server with IIS installed. I also installed Windows git extensions on this machine. The remote git URL looks like this : "https://username@server.domain.fr/team_folder/project.git".

On the web server, when I want to push something on a remote repository from the git bash, an openSSH popup is displayed and my Windows password is asked. If I enter the correct password, the push is performed. This is caused by the "askpass" configuration.

```
core.askpass = C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass
```

If I remove this configuration's parameter, git prompt for the password in the command window. Normal...

My question : we use kerberos for authentication, so is it possible to realize the push operation without asking the password to the user ? And how ?. I tried to configure putty but with no success for the moment (like I wrote, I'm not a specialist of authentication).

For now I use git-credential-winstore that I modified for not asking password (which is not usable on IIS server side). When git ask GCW to get password, it simply returns an empty password. So git ends with a return code <> 0 and my application ask the user for password, call GCW to store it and call git a second time to execute the command. It works but I'm pretty sure this is not the best solution.

Comment: git 2.8 should make this working, with `git config http.emptyAuth true`. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35626581/6309)

Answer (score 1):

> we use kerberos for authentication, so is it possible to realize the push operation without asking the password to the user ?

Yes, starting with git 2.8+ (March 2016)

And how ?

```
git config http.emptyAuth true
```

That will **force an empty username and password** during http authentication:

See [commit 121061f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/121061f67fd47aed5b2f3a7deb82af15215636bd) (15 Feb 2016) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 65ba75b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/65ba75ba7daae3298139f18cf866a23d01f4dd48), 24 Feb 2016)</sup>

> ### `http`: add option to try authentication without username
>
> Performing GSS-Negotiate authentication using Kerberos does not require specifying a username or password, since that information is already
>   included in the ticket itself.
>   However, `libcurl` refuses to perform authentication if it has not been provided with a username and password.
>
> **Add an option, `http.emptyAuth`, that provides `libcurl` with an empty username and password to make it attempt authentication anyway.**

The [`git config` documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/121061f67fd47aed5b2f3a7deb82af15215636bd/Documentation/config.txt#L1603-L1607) will read:

```
http.emptyAuth:
```

> Attempt authentication without seeking a username or password.
>   This can be used to attempt GSS-Negotiate authentication without specifying a username in the URL, as `libcurl` normally requires a username for authentication.

Note: that supports `http://:@gitserver.example.com`, and since Git 2.11+ (Q4 2016), it also supports `http://@gitserver.example.com`, forcing a NULL username if `http.emptyauth` is set.

See [commit 5275c30](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5275c3081c2b2c6166a2fc6b253a3acb20f8ae89) (04 Oct 2016) by [David Turner (`csusbdt`)](https://github.com/csusbdt).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c6400bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c6400bf8d5437e7614c86e6b027761e11ed7a1be), 17 Oct 2016)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Though, this is clearly off topic here, I'd answer anyway (Unix server, any client):

1. Install [`mod_spnego`](https://github.com/lha/mod_spnego)
2. Configure `mod_spnego`
3. Install Git on Windows, make sure that the supplied `libcurl` has been compiled against SSPI (`--with-sspi`)
4. Install Git on Unix, make sure that the linked `libcurl` has been compiled against GSS-API (`--with-gssapi`)

The way `libcurl` is called from Git, `ANYAUTH` is chosen with a default username+password (`:`). That's it. `libcurl` should do the rest.

Works like a charm here against external repositories over a SPNEGO-protected proxy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but why it is "clearly off topic" here ? I post recently on the site and maybe I don't know all the rules, so I'd like to know.

Comment: I have not the ability to modify our Unix environment, so I think your answer don't work for me. I can only modify the Windows server side.

Comment: @P.Debrabant, is the Windows server used as HTTP server or as mere client?

Comment: The windows Server, where my web Intranet application is hosting is therefore a client against the Unix Server.